# EXCEL: Change dates that occur in a range across months into the last month of the range

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I work for a retail company, and receive a daily excel report including all SKUs on order and their 'ship date', which can span any day of the month. What I need to do is generalize these ship dates into "delivery months", or what month we will actually receipt the goods at our fulfillment center. So for example, any SKU with a ship date falling between 1/15/17 and 2/15/17 would have a delivery month of 2/17, etc.

I've tried playing around with the Month() function but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Hard to help without some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(DAY(A1)<15,DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Format column **B** to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student! That worked a treat - I'm just a little ashamed I didn't figure that out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try something like this

In B2

```
=IF(DAY(A2)<=15,EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1,EOMONTH(A2,0)+1)
```